# Стоит ли учить такую песню?

Tags: литература, обучение, общие-вопросы

Ребёнку в школе дали отпечатанный на бумаге текст песни с целью выучить наизусть (видимо, какой-то школьный гимн). Вот первый куплет и припев (орфография оригинала сохранена):

> Мы идем дорогою детства
>
> Нашей дружной великой стране
>
> И друзья что живут по соседству
>
> И тебе подпевают и мне
>
> Эта песня откроет границы
>
> Вместе соединит города
>
> Если вдруг тебе загрустится
>
> Ты запой эту песню тогда
>
> Припев:
>
> Вместе петь танцевать веселится
>
> Видеть ваши счастливые лица
>
> Позабыть все невзгоды на свете
>
> И улыбки дарить друзьям
>
> То на нашей огромной планете
>
> Был бы мир были счастливы дети
>
> И тогда будет радость всем нам

У меня возникли сомнения, будет ли полезным заучивание такого текста, и если будет, то с какой точки зрения (что полезного это принесёт?). Попозже отсканирую песню целиком и выложу где-нибудь сбоку, чтобы не засорять форум.

В песне 10 куплетов (и, соответственно, 10 раз повторяется припев), в свете чего возникает ещё и Галактионовский вопрос: сколько же времени потребуется конкретной ученице 1 "б" класса, чтобы выучить *это* наизусть?

upd 2013-09-26 ============

Я не первый год общаюсь с работниками образования. До этого было 4 года в садике. Там часто давали учить стихи, обычно не очень складные. И я достаточно часто их подправлял, как мог (чтобы получалось более складно). Но вот эту школьную песню я просто не представляю с какого бока начать править.

Долго думал. Вероятно, во второй строчке должно быть "**ПО** нашей великой стране". Но куда вставить недостающее "если" для строки "То на нашей огромной планете"?

И попросту удручает общее количество слов, в разных комбинациях повторяющих друг друга.

Comment: Бегемотус нашёл уже ссылку на полный текст и выложил ниже. Только открывайте осторожно, лучше с отключенным javascript в браузере. Не нажимайте там никакие лишние кнопки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это точно не поэзия (да и не проза, впрочем). Заставлять учить такой текст  жестоко.

Answer (score 6):

Эээ... корректор этому тексту не помешает явно. Но проблема не в этом. Проблема в том, что многие авторы думают, будто достаточно написать "правильные и нужные" слова, кое-как их зарифмовать - и готов хороший стих или песенный текст. А в художественном поэтическом тексте такой подход недопустим. Он порождает трескучие декларации, наборы штампов и банальностей, не прививает моральные ценности, а, напротив, вызывает раздражение по отношению к ним, и в итоге приучает мыслить трюизмами. Ну, посмотрите сами: тут же нет ни одной свежей, действительно искренней строчки, а есть целые фразы, надерганные из старых хороших и не очень песен советской эпохи.
К тому же в стихе важна техника, а тут техника... (схватилась за голову)... рифмы слабые, ритм и размер не выдержаны. Явно не поэт писал. Прошу прощенья, но моя 9-летняя дочь, и та написала бы лучше.

Answer (score 3):

Да уж... Содержание еще более-менее, но полное игнорирование  знаков препинания осложняет чтение.  А явная потеря некоторых слов (просится "в" во 2-ую строчку и "если" в предложении с "то") создает впечатление, что автор слов не очень дружит с русским языком (иностранец?). Еще, как вариант, неточный набор на компьютере. Но такие вещи надо проверять!

Про 10 куплетов молчу... Может, на каждую параллель по куплету? Иначе совсем тяжко...

P.S. В детском саду как-то ребенку давали учить слова для сказки. В одном четверостишии по рифме надо было говорить "свеклА". Изменить не получилось, пришлось так и говорить. К счастью, ребенок все же говорит в обычной жизни правильно.

Моей тоже выдали слова гимна школы. Обязательно изучу. На слух вроде ничего, патриотично)))

Answer (score 3):

По-мому, это ужас, летящий на чём попало. Я не вижу тут никакой разницы с поминаемой недобрым словом эстрадой:

> Что бы счастливо жить и забыть про
> проблемы Улыбайся и пой не меняй этой
> темы Ты свободно живи никогда не
> рисуйся И друзей собери вместе с ними
> тусуйся И увидешь что все будет проще
> простого Ты пойми "нельзя" это просто
> лишь слово Это просто предлог для тех
> кто не хочет Ты же с нами ты знаешь
> что все будет проще Мы дорогою детства
> шагаем с тобой

Я читаю: «дружно вместе любая гадость — не гадость, потому что мы такие замечательные весёлые ребята». Я бы на месте мамы тоже не захотела, чтобы мой ребёнок это учил.

Answer (score 2):

Да это же форменное издевательство над русским языком! Как можно давать (в Школе!)детям то, что учит их говорить по-русски неправильно. Да и школьный гимн из 10 куплетов... Цель какая? Отвращение  вызвать к школе и учению?

Answer (score 0):

А что плохого в этой песне? Или Вы очень боитесь, что Ваш ребенок научится дружить и делать людей рядом счастливыми? Или, по-Вашему, это несовременно, да? Лучше жить для себя по принципу "съешь, пока не съел другой"? 
И какие по вашему мнению тогда нужно учить песни? "Жить нужно в кайф"? Или "Чем выше любовь, тем ниже поцелуи"?
А на счет времени заучивания - боитесь, что мозги перегрузит? А там, глядишь и - о ужас! - думать начнет... Люди "Евгения Онегина" наизусть знают, а в античные времена каждый образованный человек знал наизусть "Иллиаду" и "Одиссею". И никто от перенапряжения мозгов не умер.

Comment: Как раз наоборот - боюсь, что от такой "иллиады" ребёнок думать разучится (а грамотность уж точно не увеличится).

Ну, и кстати (раз уж разговор сам зашёл), @Noble, 

>большая просьба оставить свою манеру оскорблять спрашивающих. Каждый Ваш ответ обязательно содержит долю желчи. Как минимум, это неприятно.

Comment: Подумал, что нужен комментарий. Я плюсанул предыдущее за мысль " думать разучится". Оскорблений, однако, в ответе не заметил.

Comment: @behemothus, слова об оскорблениях - _цитата_ из сообщения участника @Noble, адресованного @yupaz (в комментариях к http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/20840#20842). 

Это как бы намёк: почему ирония @yupaz - это оскорбление, а ирония @Noble - нет?

Comment: Я видел, что цитата, но не вникал. Но дело нее в этом. Мне надо было сказать, что плюс не за разборки, кои я даже не читал, а за "разучится думать".

Comment: Согласна с behemothus. Не вижу ничего плохого в этой песне (кроме грамотности, конечно). И уж, действительно, всяко лучше, чем "Чем выше любовь, тем ниже поцелуи". Пусть ребенок лучше такое учит, чем слушает современную аудиопорнушку, в которую превратились песни.

Comment: @Fuchoin Kazuki, да пусть слушает, это действительно безобиднее "эстрады". Но ведь это не слушать, а _учить наизусть_ заставляют! Вы могли бы такое выучить?

Answer (score 0):

Если это правда дано для заучивания, то это клиника. 
Я не в курсе современных школьных заморочек, но это пора нести в РОНО (или как оно там нынче). Или сразу - в прокуратуру. У классной явно в любовниках ходит какой-то графоман-песенник.

Какие уж тут знаки препинания, если уже во второй строчке нет никакой грамматики.
Про художесвенную ценность - ваще малчу.

Интересно, а кто дописал еще шесть куплетов?
Вам точно не в трех экземплярах вручили?
xxxxxxxx.ru/xxxxxxxx/xxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx_xxxxxx.html

Comment: ха! вот уж не думал, что они это с интернета скачали! Вот это номер! Но ссылку лучше, наверное, уберите - там какие-то программы начинают лезть на компьютер, боюсь, что вирусы.

Comment: Нет, на вирусы не похоже. 
Впрочем, как скажете.  
Гугл все равно находит по первым строчкам.

Answer (score 0):

А можно узнать, что конкретно, кроме грамотности, конечно, Вас смущает в этой песне?

Comment: Конечно. 

1. Тут даже не грамотность. Я не знаю, как это назвать: "Мы идём нашей стране..." - на каком это языке вообще?

2. Размер песни. Наберите в Гугле первые слова, и найдёте весь текст (говорит Бегемотус). Там целый печатный лист. Мне жалко заставлять ребёнка учить это всё (содержание там примерно повторяется). Если честно, я не представляю, что мог бы выучить это сам.

Comment: Ничего не смущает, кроме формы и содержания.

Comment: А это: "если вдруг тебе загрустится". О, редактор подчеркивает последнее слово, не знает! Я думаю, надо говорить "взгрустнется". Но это в ритм и рифму не влазит. Впрочем, с ритмом там вообще проблемы. 

И чего бы не разучить "С чего начинается Родина?" или что-то такого же качества? :(

Answer (score 0):

Не исключено, что текст был сосканирован или перенабран "от руки" - тогда некоторые очевидные нелепости, в т.ч. отсутствие знаков препинания, объяснимы.

Comment: Да. Или клавиатура была очень старая, и знаки препинания на ней все "запали". Правда, неясно, почему тогда сохранились двоеточия после слова "Припев"?

Answer (score 0):

времени, думаю, не потребовалось бы много: во-первых, это песня с повторяющимся припевом, во-вторых, текст песни учится быстрее, чем просто стихотворение.
А вот грамотность там оставляет желать лучшего. Видно, какой-то не сильно грамотный родитель перепечатывал...
Содержание-то вполне нормальное, по крайней мере, приведенного тут отрывка. И это просто школьный гимн, возможно, детьми и сочиненный, поэтому может иметь какие-то недочеты...
Но, конечно, текст бы следовало значительно доработать, а уж потом давать детям для заучивания.

Comment: Да это текстом можно назвать с большой натяжкой. В тексте предложения связаны по смыслу и грамматически. А здесь нет грамматической связи даже между словами  в предложениях. Какая радость?! Тут глубокая печаль всем нам! (Ой, скоро разучусь говорить по-русски!)